# WSO2 BPS 3.2 causes a NoClassDefFoundError when executing a BPEL Process

Tags: wso2

I have a BPEL deployed on WSO2 BPS 3.2.0 that invokes a webservice from w3schools.com and returns the result back to the BPEL invoker. When executing the BPEL service through SoapUI, i received a Timeout Exception, however upon close observation in the logs, i came across this error

```
TID: [0] [BPS] [2014-08-19 19:04:02,827] ERROR {org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU} -  Method "run" in class "org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.INVOKE" threw an unexpected exception. {org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/synapse/core/axis2/SOAPUtils
    at org.wso2.carbon.unifiedendpoint.core.UnifiedEndpointHandler.handleMessageOutput(UnifiedEndpointHandler.java:105)
    at org.wso2.carbon.unifiedendpoint.core.UnifiedEndpointHandler.invoke(UnifiedEndpointHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:261)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:426)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.utils.AxisServiceUtils.invokeService(AxisServiceUtils.java:305)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.PartnerService.invoke(PartnerService.java:324)
    at org.wso2.carbon.bpel.core.ode.integration.BPELMessageExchangeContextImpl.invokePartner(BPELMessageExchangeContextImpl.java:43)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.invoke(BpelRuntimeContextImpl.java:793)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.INVOKE.run(INVOKE.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor40.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU$JacobThreadImpl.run(JacobVPU.java:451)
    at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU.execute(JacobVPU.java:139)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.execute(BpelRuntimeContextImpl.java:898)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.PartnerLinkMyRoleImpl.invokeNewInstance(PartnerLinkMyRoleImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess$1.invoke(BpelProcess.java:283)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.invokeProcess(BpelProcess.java:224)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.invokeProcess(BpelProcess.java:279)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.handleJobDetails(BpelProcess.java:434)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.onScheduledJob(BpelEngineImpl.java:558)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelServerImpl.onScheduledJob(BpelServerImpl.java:467)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:536)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:530)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:280)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:235)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob.call(SimpleScheduler.java:530)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob.call(SimpleScheduler.java:514)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SOAPUtils
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 37 more
```

Upon close inspection , it seems that the %CARBON_HOME%/repository/components/plugins  folder doesnt contain the

> synapse-core_2.1.2.wso2v4.jar

I tried placing the jar file directly in the folder, and have also tried using the patch mechansim

> 1. Created a folder patch0006 in  %CARBON_HOME%/repository/components/patches
> 2. Place the jar file in this new folder
> 3. Restart the server
> 4. Patch Mechanism successfully places the file in %CARBON_HOME%/repository/components/plugins folder.

But to no avail, the server still is unable to find the SOAPUtils class file. Any ideas, how to proceed further ?

Comment: Just to quickly add, i have the default installation of BPS3.2.0 downloaded from wso2 website.